# Why do I have the Ubuntu OS although I uninstalled it?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

When booting my PC with Windows 8 as my main OS, my Computer shows me two Operating Systems to boot either I uninstalled Ubuntu. I also can´t uninstall Ubuntu anymore and if I install a new Ubuntu again there are two "Ubuntu" options when choosing my OS, but only one of it works.
I´d really prefer to have one working Ubuntu system or no Ubuntu OS. **How can i delete the not working Ubuntu?**

Sorry for mistakes i´m from Austria.

Comment: What happens when you try to boot into your non existing Ubuntu partion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct MBR entry. 
Im long time  not using win but in theory you should boot your win installation disc go to repair than from command prompt issue a command to correct mbr
or even easier you can use programs  like `EasyBcD` to correct your win bootloader. Such programs offer a GUI approach to correct MBR entries, thus easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

How did you uninstall Ubuntu? The general way of doing it is using Windows System Rescue CD to restore Windows bootloader, delete the partition (either using a Live CD or Windows Disk Management), and then extending your Windows partition to consume the space you just freed up.

That would also be the way to fix your current set up, and remove Ubuntu cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Download `Visual BCD Editor` for Windows. When you run it, you'll see an option to delete the entry for your non-existing Ubuntu installation.